# Long term effects of using modafinil on cognition

Tags: memory, long-term-memory

What are the Long term effects of using stimulant like modafinil on cognition abilty?

Comment: This question is very broad. Restricting and editing the question to one class of stimulants and one type of cognitive effect may make this question better answerable.